# Anonymous table cells - do they affect reflow/repaint performance?

Tags: html, css, performance, dom

The good old micro clearfix hack is based on using a blank table element to prevent margin-collapse and clear floats. It mentions that this behavior creates anonymous table elements as each HTML table needs those to exist by design, so to my understanding the repaint cycle has 6 new blank elements for each clearfixed element to deal with (table + anon row + anon cell * 2). Does this have any drawbacks relevant to performance during the reflow/repaint cycle? How would you test this?

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: How is this question primarily opinion-based? Unless you consider each implementation as an "opinion".

Comment: No idea, anonymous table cells are a reality.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't pollute the DOM, but the objects may be computed for rendering purposes. Implementations may be able to optimise them out.

But all kinds of boxes are computed during the rendering process. There's no specific need to be concerned about these.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for something less speculative. You basically said you don't know.

Comment: Not at all. I basically said "no".

Comment: You can't have 6000 extra elements on a test page of 1000 list items "computed" and have exactly zero effect. Sure, there may be optimizations - but "may be" doesn't qualify as an answer - you would suspect as much without anyone mentioning it.

Comment: @mystrdat: I think he means "no, anonymous table cells don't pollute the DOM". Because anonymous boxes don't represent anything in the DOM - that's why they're called anonymous boxes. But that doesn't address the part about reflow/repaint, which I suspect is what you're *really* interested in knowing.

Comment: Ah I see, actually points out a mistake in my question - I'm aware pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM tree itself, but they are rendered and may very well affect the repaint cycle as you say.
My mistake @Alohci, I will correct the question.